# PHP cURL - POST is being sent to an empty page?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to automate the usage of [this site](https://temp-mail.org/en/option/change/), where users can use temporary E-Mail addresses which can also be specified by them manually. It uses a very simple anti-spam protection by having this `<input name="csrf" type="hidden">` input inside the form with a randomized set of characters, which then needs to be included in the POST request. So, if the CSRF is `bj152nvua2ob`, and I want my new address to be "john@l0real.net", my POST needs to be:

```
csrf=bj152nvua2ob&mail=john&domain=@l0real.net
```

Problem is, I can't do this with cURL and PHP. Here's the top of my code:

```
$ch = curl_init ();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "temp-mail.org/en/option/change/");
// Without CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, the page is not going to load.
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");

$html = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Then, after I've got the response, I start generating a new mail address and start getting the CSRF, therefore I've written two simple functions called "generate_mail" and ["get_csrf"](https://pastebin.com/tEFpnzEH). I've tested both of them, and they seem to work without any issues.

```
$csrf = get_csrf ($html);
$mail = generate_mail ();
$post = "csrf=$csrf&mail=$mail&domain=@l0real.net";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

file_put_contents ("final_response.html", curl_exec ($ch));

curl_close ($ch);
```

After creating the file `final_response.html` on my PC and then viewing it, I've noticed that the results aren't what I've expected. Some tries later, I've decided to debug my connection using Fiddler, and then I've noticed something interesting. This is what I get when I use this site with my browser:
[image: with my browser]

and this with cURL:
[image: with cURL].

Notice how there is 1 element (excluding the tunnels) against... 4! First element is an empty response, but the second one contains the HTML page. Last two are the same: third is an empty response (and that's where my POST was sent), and forth contains the HTML page with different CSRF and incorrect mail address (the one that was generated by the site itself, not by me). From what I can tell, each time I use `curl_exec`, it first loads an empty page, but then loads the correct one. All of my requests are being sent to the empty one, thus being ignored later on. Is this a security measure, or I didn't configure cURL correctly? I've tried to provide as much information as I could, showcasing each, and every step of mine, hoping that this problem can be fixed.

Comment: You might want to encode before you send.

Comment: Even if I won't send anything and right after the first `curl_exec` I use `curl_close`, I'm still going to get a blank and a correct page, where with browser I only get the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding these lines of code:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $path_to_cookies);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $path_to_cookies);
```

Now, it works the way intended!